# Is it possible to open an eclipse gui project in netbeans gui builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have made a swing application in eclipse using windowBuilder addon, But because it is a extremly not userfriendy i want to move my project to netbeans gui builder to continue my work, Is it possible and if so then how do i manage it?

Comment: Most likely not. Another downside of GUI builders.

Comment: `i want to move my project to netbeans gui builder` - don't move you project to another tool, then you will still be restricted by that tool. Just maintain the code manually and use the IDE for its debugging/testing features. Don't use the tool to generated your code.